# Different gradle output in Github Actions VM and local

Tags: gradle, github-actions

I'm trying to setup a simple Github Action in order to use gradle to build a Java application. This is my action:

```
name: Build with gradle and deploy to GKE cluster

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]

env:
  ...

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build app
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11.0.7 for x64
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: '11.0.7'
          architecture: x64
      - run: chmod +x ./uCampusLibs/domainObjects/gradlew
      - run: ./uCampusLibs/domainObjects/gradlew build
```

When I execute this action, in the output of the gradle command I can see that only one task has been executed, and no build artifacts are created (not even the `build` dir is created). However, the step is marked as successful.
However, if I run the same commands in my local system (also Ubuntu, same OpenJDK version), 4 tasks are executed and the build snapshot is created under the `build` dir as expected.

Do you have any clue about what might be going on?

Comment: The purpose of running gradle is to see the same output or to get the correct result? I don't see how this question can be useful to anyone else. Besides, I don't think it is possible that the output in gh-actions is any different from what you are used to, locally unless you have not use the same settings or the same commands

Comment: @smac89 of course the point of running gradle is getting the correct result, something I'm not getting as no build artifacts are generated as result of the Github Action. I just pointed that the output is different in order to provide more (hopefully useful) information

Comment: Ok I think I'm starting to understand your question. Did you include an action that saves the build artifacts? See [`actions/upload-artifact`](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact)

Comment: Unless you are pushing something different to GitHub, the wrapper version will guarantee that anything you execute will be the same – for all supported platforms. The output from Gradle might be different due to `org.gradle.console = verbose` (which you might have set in your laptop/desktop, but not in GitHuh Actions).

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem was that in the Github Action I tried to execute directly the `gradlew` script from the root directory of the project, while locally I executed the script from the artifact's directory. Therefore, the solution was changing the step to this:

```
  - run: ./gradlew build
    working-directory: ./uCampusLibs/domainObjects/
```